# What packages are installed by default on Ubuntu Cloud Image?

Tags: server, 14.04, cloud, vagrant

I am running Ubuntu in a virtual machine through Vagrant using the "ubuntu/trusty64" box.  Based on the information on https://vagrantcloud.com/, this box runs a "Cloud Image" of Ubuntu.

I'm having some issues with some private code, and as part of the debugging process, would like to know exactly what packages are on the image, and particularly how the cloud image differs from the Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop.

So far, my research has turned up a [blog post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428918/vagrant-equivalent-to-ubuntu-12-04-3-lts-ami-83e2dcea) from when it first launched stating that the image was "rather vanilla" with no further detail.  I've also turned up the following question, which is similar to mine, but was never answered.
So, what are the differences between Ubuntu Cloud Image and Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2):

The [manifest file](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-i386.manifest) for the cloud image contains a list of all the packages installed on the cloud image:

```
accountsservice 0.6.35-0ubuntu7.3
acpid 1:2.0.21-1ubuntu2
adduser 3.113+nmu3ubuntu3
apparmor 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3
apport 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21
apport-symptoms 0.20
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2.15
apt-transport-https 1.0.1ubuntu2.15
apt-utils 1.0.1ubuntu2.15
apt-xapian-index 0.45ubuntu4
aptitude 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4
aptitude-common 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4
at 3.1.14-1ubuntu1
base-files 7.2ubuntu5.5
base-passwd 3.5.33
bash 4.3-7ubuntu1.5
bash-completion 1:2.1-4ubuntu0.2
bc 1.06.95-8ubuntu1
bind9-host 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
bsdmainutils 9.0.5ubuntu1
bsdutils 1:2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7
busybox-initramfs 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1
busybox-static 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1
byobu 5.77-0ubuntu1.2
bzip2 1.0.6-5
ca-certificates 20160104ubuntu0.14.04.1
cloud-guest-utils 0.27-0ubuntu9.2
cloud-init 0.7.5-0ubuntu1.20
command-not-found 0.3ubuntu12
command-not-found-data 0.3ubuntu12
console-setup 1.70ubuntu8
coreutils 8.21-1ubuntu5.4
cpio 2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2
cron 3.0pl1-124ubuntu2
cryptsetup 2:1.6.1-1ubuntu1
cryptsetup-bin 2:1.6.1-1ubuntu1
curl 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.10
dash 0.5.7-4ubuntu1
dbus 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.4
debconf 1.5.51ubuntu2
debconf-i18n 1.5.51ubuntu2
debianutils 4.4
dh-python 1.20140128-1ubuntu8.2
diffutils 1:3.3-1
dmidecode 2.12-2
dmsetup 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2
dnsutils 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
dosfstools 3.0.26-1ubuntu0.1
dpkg 1.17.5ubuntu5.7
e2fslibs:i386 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3
e2fsprogs 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3
eatmydata 26-2
ed 1.9-2
eject 2.1.5+deb1+cvs20081104-13.1
ethtool 1:3.13-1
file 1:5.14-2ubuntu3.3
findutils 4.4.2-7
fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console 0.80-0ubuntu6
friendly-recovery 0.2.25
ftp 0.17-28
fuse 2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1
gawk 1:4.0.1+dfsg-2.1ubuntu2
gcc-4.8-base:i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
gcc-4.9-base:i386 4.9.3-0ubuntu4
gdisk 0.8.8-1ubuntu0.1
geoip-database 20140313-1
gettext-base 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3
gir1.2-glib-2.0 1.40.0-1ubuntu0.2
gnupg 1.4.16-1ubuntu2.4
gpgv 1.4.16-1ubuntu2.4
grep 2.16-1
groff-base 1.22.2-5
grub-common 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.12
grub-gfxpayload-lists 0.6
grub-legacy-ec2 0.7.5-0ubuntu1.20
grub-pc 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.12
grub-pc-bin 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.12
grub2-common 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.12
gzip 1.6-3ubuntu1
hdparm 9.43-1ubuntu3
hostname 3.15ubuntu1
ifupdown 0.7.47.2ubuntu4.4
info 5.2.0.dfsg.1-2
init-system-helpers 1.14
initramfs-tools 0.103ubuntu4.4
initramfs-tools-bin 0.103ubuntu4.4
initscripts 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.3
insserv 1.14.0-5ubuntu2
install-info 5.2.0.dfsg.1-2
iproute2 3.12.0-2ubuntu1
iptables 1.4.21-1ubuntu1
iputils-ping 3:20121221-4ubuntu1.1
iputils-tracepath 3:20121221-4ubuntu1.1
irqbalance 1.0.6-2ubuntu0.14.04.4
isc-dhcp-client 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8
isc-dhcp-common 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8
iso-codes 3.52-1
kbd 1.15.5-1ubuntu1
keyboard-configuration 1.70ubuntu8
klibc-utils 2.0.3-0ubuntu1.14.04.2
kmod 15-0ubuntu6
krb5-locales 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2
landscape-client 14.12-0ubuntu0.14.04
landscape-common 14.12-0ubuntu0.14.04
language-selector-common 0.129.3
laptop-detect 0.13.7ubuntu2
less 458-2
libaccountsservice0:i386 0.6.35-0ubuntu7.3
libacl1:i386 2.2.52-1
libapparmor-perl 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3
libapparmor1:i386 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3
libapt-inst1.5:i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.15
libapt-pkg4.12:i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.15
libarchive-extract-perl 0.70-1
libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libasprintf0c2:i386 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3
libattr1:i386 1:2.4.47-1ubuntu1
libaudit-common 1:2.3.2-2ubuntu1
libaudit1:i386 1:2.3.2-2ubuntu1
libbind9-90 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
libblkid1:i386 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7
libboost-iostreams1.54.0:i386 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1
libbsd0:i386 0.6.0-2ubuntu1
libbz2-1.0:i386 1.0.6-5
libc-bin 2.19-0ubuntu6.9
libc6:i386 2.19-0ubuntu6.9
libcap-ng0 0.7.3-1ubuntu2
libcap2:i386 1:2.24-0ubuntu2
libcap2-bin 1:2.24-0ubuntu2
libcgmanager0:i386 0.24-0ubuntu7.5
libck-connector0:i386 0.4.5-3.1ubuntu2
libclass-accessor-perl 0.34-1
libcomerr2:i386 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3
libcryptsetup4 2:1.6.1-1ubuntu1
libcurl3:i386 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.10
libcurl3-gnutls:i386 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.10
libcwidget3 0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1
libdb5.3:i386 5.3.28-3ubuntu3
libdbus-1-3:i386 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.4
libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 0.100.2-1
libdebconfclient0:i386 0.187ubuntu1
libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2
libdns100 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
libdrm2:i386 2.4.67-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
libdumbnet1 1.12-4build1
libedit2:i386 3.1-20130712-2
libelf1:i386 0.158-0ubuntu5.2
libept1.4.12:i386 1.0.12
libestr0 0.1.9-0ubuntu2
libevent-2.0-5:i386 2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1.14.04.1
libexpat1:i386 2.1.0-4ubuntu1.3
libffi6:i386 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12ubuntu0.1
libfreetype6:i386 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5
libfribidi0:i386 0.19.6-1
libfuse2:i386 2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1
libgc1c2:i386 1:7.2d-5ubuntu2
libgcc1:i386 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4
libgck-1-0:i386 3.10.1-1
libgcr-3-common 3.10.1-1
libgcr-base-3-1:i386 3.10.1-1
libgcrypt11:i386 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.4
libgdbm3:i386 1.8.3-12build1
libgeoip1:i386 1.6.0-1
libgirepository-1.0-1 1.40.0-1ubuntu0.2
libglib2.0-0:i386 2.40.2-0ubuntu1
libglib2.0-data 2.40.2-0ubuntu1
libgnutls-openssl27:i386 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.5
libgnutls26:i386 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.5
libgpg-error0:i386 1.12-0.2ubuntu1
libgpm2:i386 1.20.4-6.1
libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2
libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libicu52:i386 52.1-3ubuntu0.4
libidn11:i386 1.28-1ubuntu2.1
libio-string-perl 1.08-3
libisc95 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
libisccc90 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
libisccfg90 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
libjson-c2:i386 0.11-3ubuntu1.2
libjson0:i386 0.11-3ubuntu1.2
libk5crypto3:i386 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2
libkeyutils1:i386 1.5.6-1
libklibc 2.0.3-0ubuntu1.14.04.2
libkmod2:i386 15-0ubuntu6
libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libkrb5-3:i386 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2
libkrb5support0:i386 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2
libldap-2.4-2:i386 2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3
liblocale-gettext-perl 1.05-7build3
liblockfile-bin 1.09-6ubuntu1
liblockfile1:i386 1.09-6ubuntu1
liblog-message-simple-perl 0.10-1
liblwres90 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10
liblzma5:i386 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2
libmagic1:i386 1:5.14-2ubuntu3.3
libmodule-pluggable-perl 5.1-1
libmount1:i386 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7
libmpdec2:i386 2.4.0-6
libncurses5:i386 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1
libncursesw5:i386 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1
libnewt0.52:i386 0.52.15-2ubuntu5
libnfnetlink0:i386 1.0.1-2
libnih-dbus1:i386 1.0.3-4ubuntu25
libnih1:i386 1.0.3-4ubuntu25
libnuma1:i386 2.0.9~rc5-1ubuntu3.14.04.2
libp11-kit0:i386 0.20.2-2ubuntu2
libpam-cap:i386 1:2.24-0ubuntu2
libpam-modules:i386 1.1.8-1ubuntu2.2
libpam-modules-bin 1.1.8-1ubuntu2.2
libpam-runtime 1.1.8-1ubuntu2.2
libpam-systemd:i386 204-5ubuntu20.19
libpam0g:i386 1.1.8-1ubuntu2.2
libparse-debianchangelog-perl 1.2.0-1ubuntu1
libparted0debian1:i386 2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1
libpcap0.8:i386 1.5.3-2
libpci3:i386 1:3.2.1-1ubuntu5.1
libpcre3:i386 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3
libpipeline1:i386 1.3.0-1
libplymouth2:i386 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1
libpng12-0:i386 1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.2
libpod-latex-perl 0.61-1
libpolkit-agent-1-0:i386 0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1
libpolkit-backend-1-0:i386 0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1
libpolkit-gobject-1-0:i386 0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1
libpopt0:i386 1.16-8ubuntu1
libprocps3:i386 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2.2
libpython-stdlib:i386 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
libpython2.7:i386 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
libpython2.7-minimal:i386 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
libpython3-stdlib:i386 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
libpython3.4-minimal:i386 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5
libpython3.4-stdlib:i386 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5
libreadline6:i386 6.3-4ubuntu2
libroken18-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
librtmp0:i386 2.4+20121230.gitdf6c518-1
libsasl2-2:i386 2.1.25.dfsg1-17build1
libsasl2-modules:i386 2.1.25.dfsg1-17build1
libsasl2-modules-db:i386 2.1.25.dfsg1-17build1
libselinux1:i386 2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1
libsemanage-common 2.2-1
libsemanage1:i386 2.2-1
libsepol1:i386 2.2-1ubuntu0.1
libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2
libsigsegv2:i386 2.10-2
libslang2:i386 2.2.4-15ubuntu1
libsqlite3-0:i386 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1
libss2:i386 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3
libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21
libstdc++6:i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
libsub-name-perl 0.05-1build4
libsystemd-daemon0:i386 204-5ubuntu20.19
libsystemd-login0:i386 204-5ubuntu20.19
libtasn1-6:i386 3.4-3ubuntu0.4
libterm-ui-perl 0.42-1
libtext-charwidth-perl 0.04-7build3
libtext-iconv-perl 1.7-5build2
libtext-soundex-perl 3.4-1build1
libtext-wrapi18n-perl 0.06-7
libtimedate-perl 2.3000-1
libtinfo5:i386 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1
libudev1:i386 204-5ubuntu20.19
libusb-0.1-4:i386 2:0.1.12-23.3ubuntu1
libusb-1.0-0:i386 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2
libustr-1.0-1:i386 1.0.4-3ubuntu2
libuuid1:i386 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7
libwind0-heimdal:i386 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
libwrap0:i386 7.6.q-25
libx11-6:i386 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2
libx11-data 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2
libxapian22 1.2.16-2ubuntu1
libxau6:i386 1:1.0.8-1
libxcb1:i386 1.10-2ubuntu1
libxdmcp6:i386 1:1.1.1-1
libxext6:i386 2:1.3.2-1ubuntu0.0.14.04.1
libxml2:i386 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.8
libxmuu1:i386 2:1.1.1-1
libxtables10 1.4.21-1ubuntu1
libyaml-0-2:i386 0.1.4-3ubuntu3.1
linux-headers-3.13.0-105 3.13.0-105.152
linux-headers-3.13.0-105-generic 3.13.0-105.152
linux-headers-generic 3.13.0.105.113
linux-headers-virtual 3.13.0.105.113
linux-image-3.13.0-105-generic 3.13.0-105.152
linux-image-virtual 3.13.0.105.113
linux-virtual 3.13.0.105.113
locales 2.13+git20120306-12.1
lockfile-progs 0.1.17
login 1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.2
logrotate 3.8.7-1ubuntu1
lsb-base 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6.2
lsb-release 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6.2
lshw 02.16-2ubuntu1.3
lsof 4.86+dfsg-1ubuntu2
ltrace 0.7.3-4ubuntu5.1
makedev 2.3.1-93ubuntu1
man-db 2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1
manpages 3.54-1ubuntu1
mawk 1.3.3-17ubuntu2
mime-support 3.54ubuntu1.1
mlocate 0.26-1ubuntu1
module-init-tools 15-0ubuntu6
mount 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7
mountall 2.53
mtr-tiny 0.85-2
multiarch-support 2.19-0ubuntu6.9
nano 2.2.6-1ubuntu1
ncurses-base 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1
ncurses-bin 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1
ncurses-term 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1
net-tools 1.60-25ubuntu2.1
netbase 5.2
netcat-openbsd 1.105-7ubuntu1
ntfs-3g 1:2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2
ntpdate 1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.04.10
open-vm-tools 2:9.4.0-1280544-5ubuntu6.2
openssh-client 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
openssh-server 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
openssh-sftp-server 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8
openssl 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21
os-prober 1.63ubuntu1.1
overlayroot 0.25ubuntu1.14.04.1
parted 2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1
passwd 1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.2
patch 2.7.1-4ubuntu2.3
pciutils 1:3.2.1-1ubuntu5.1
perl 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1
perl-base 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1
perl-modules 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1
plymouth 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1
policykit-1 0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1
pollinate 4.23-0ubuntu1~14.04
popularity-contest 1.57ubuntu1
powermgmt-base 1.31build1
ppp 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2
pppconfig 2.3.19ubuntu1
pppoeconf 1.20ubuntu1
procps 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2.2
psmisc 22.20-1ubuntu2
python 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
python-apt 0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-apt-common 0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-chardet 2.0.1-2build2
python-cheetah 2.4.4-3.fakesyncbuild1
python-configobj 4.7.2+ds-5build1
python-debian 0.1.21+nmu2ubuntu2
python-gdbm 2.7.5-1ubuntu1
python-json-pointer 1.0-2build1
python-jsonpatch 1.3-4
python-minimal 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
python-oauth 1.0.1-3build2
python-openssl 0.13-2ubuntu6
python-pam 0.4.2-13.1ubuntu3
python-pkg-resources 3.3-1ubuntu2
python-prettytable 0.7.2-2ubuntu2
python-pycurl 7.19.3-0ubuntu3
python-requests 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.3
python-serial 2.6-1build1
python-six 1.5.2-1ubuntu1
python-twisted-bin 13.2.0-1ubuntu1
python-twisted-core 13.2.0-1ubuntu1
python-twisted-names 13.2.0-1ubuntu1
python-twisted-web 13.2.0-1ubuntu1
python-urllib3 1.7.1-1ubuntu4
python-xapian 1.2.16-2ubuntu1
python-yaml 3.10-4ubuntu0.1
python-zope.interface 4.0.5-1ubuntu4
python2.7 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
python2.7-minimal 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3
python3 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
python3-apport 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21
python3-apt 0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python3-commandnotfound 0.3ubuntu12
python3-dbus 1.2.0-2build2
python3-distupgrade 1:0.220.8
python3-gdbm:i386 3.4.3-1~14.04.2
python3-gi 3.12.0-1ubuntu1
python3-minimal 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
python3-newt 0.52.15-2ubuntu5
python3-problem-report 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21
python3-pycurl 7.19.3-0ubuntu3
python3-software-properties 0.92.37.7
python3-update-manager 1:0.196.22
python3.4 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5
python3.4-minimal 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5
readline-common 6.3-4ubuntu2
resolvconf 1.69ubuntu1.1
rsync 3.1.0-2ubuntu0.2
rsyslog 7.4.4-1ubuntu2.6
run-one 1.17-0ubuntu1
screen 4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9
sed 4.2.2-4ubuntu1
sensible-utils 0.0.9
sgml-base 1.26+nmu4ubuntu1
shared-mime-info 1.2-0ubuntu3
software-properties-common 0.92.37.7
ssh-import-id 3.21-0ubuntu1
strace 4.8-1ubuntu5
sudo 1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.3
systemd-services 204-5ubuntu20.19
systemd-shim 6-2bzr1
sysv-rc 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.3
sysvinit-utils 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.3
tar 1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1
tasksel 2.88ubuntu15
tasksel-data 2.88ubuntu15
tcpd 7.6.q-25
tcpdump 4.5.1-2ubuntu1.2
telnet 0.17-36build2
time 1.7-24
tmux 1.8-5
tzdata 2016h-0ubuntu0.14.04
ubuntu-keyring 2012.05.19
ubuntu-minimal 1.325
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core 1:0.220.8
ubuntu-standard 1.325
ucf 3.0027+nmu1
udev 204-5ubuntu20.19
ufw 0.34~rc-0ubuntu2
unattended-upgrades 0.82.1ubuntu2.4
update-manager-core 1:0.196.22
update-notifier-common 0.154.1ubuntu2
upstart 1.12.1-0ubuntu4.2
ureadahead 0.100.0-16
usbutils 1:007-2ubuntu1.1
util-linux 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7
uuid-runtime 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7
vim 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1
vim-common 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1
vim-runtime 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1
vim-tiny 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1
w3m 0.5.3-15
wget 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.2
whiptail 0.52.15-2ubuntu5
xauth 1:1.0.7-1ubuntu1
xkb-data 2.10.1-1ubuntu1
xml-core 0.13+nmu2
xz-utils 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2
zerofree 1.0.2-1ubuntu1
zlib1g:i386 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
```

It doesn't mention any modifications to any settings.

This file was found on the bottom of [this](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/release/) page.  I'm currently trying to locate the manifest for the server image, and will edit my answer once I diff the two files.